# Error while accessing network state

Tags: java, android, security, permissions, user-permissions

I want to connect my app to the internet so i put in the permission check for connecting to the internet and accessing network state:-

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MovieManiac">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

I have tried all the solutions previously posted like adding user-permission again and also clean build but nothing seems to work. I use API 22. I would really appreciate some help.The error i get is this:-

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.archit.moviemaniac, PID: 4638
java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10105 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:964)
at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:610)
at com.example.archit.moviemaniac.MovieManiac$1.onClick(MovieManiac.java:41)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4789)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19881)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Comment: try doing a clean build

Comment: i have already tried that but that does not help. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

With

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

In Android manifest you are using **user-permission**  instead of **uses-permission**  .